# Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Azure Active Directory is only supported on Windows operating systems

Tags: azure-sql-database, liquibase

We are trying to run sql files from Jenkins Linux machine using Liquibase to the Microsoft SQL server db and getting the error as:

> ERROR: Build step failed with exception java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Error getting database connection using driver
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver using url
>   jdbc:sqlserver://*********.database.windows.net:***;database=*********;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated'
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.liquibase.evaluator.AbstractLiquibaseBuilder.createJdbcConnection(AbstractLiquibaseBuilder.java:236)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.liquibase.evaluator.AbstractLiquibaseBuilder.createLiquibase(AbstractLiquibaseBuilder.java:164)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.liquibase.evaluator.AbstractLiquibaseBuilder.perform(AbstractLiquibaseBuilder.java:129)at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
>   at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
>   at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
>   Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: **Azure
>   Active Directory is only supported on Windows operating
>   systems.**at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1289)at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:773)

We have tried connecting  directly with SQL server authentication and it was successful but while using Azure service principal credential we are getting this error. How do we use Azure SPN to work with Liquibase?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to connect using active directory integrated to SQL Azure? You should try to connect using the admin server login of SQL Azure or using a login created on SQL Azure. If that is the case, please look how to create the connection string on the samples contained on below article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-java

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Alberto Morillo

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Alberto.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Alberto. We have tested the connectivity with SQL user but there are some restrictions in using the SQL login approach for our testing and hence we are trying to test this with AD

Comment: What restrictions do you have with testing?